# Derivatives of creation and annihilation operators over coordinate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-optics

I meet a problem about how to understand derivatives of creation and annihilation operators.

Let's look at the following example:

$$H=\int dr [-\hat{a}^{+}(r)\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\nabla^{2}\hat{a}(r)]\tag{1}$$

where $\hat{a}(r)$ is annihilation operator annihilating a Bose particle in position $r$.

In Eq. $(1)$, clearly, $\hat{a}(r)$ can be derivated over position.

When using Fourier transform

$$\hat{a}(r)=\sum e^{ipr}\hat{a}_{p}\tag{2}$$

$\nabla^{2} \hat{a}(r)=\sum (\nabla^{2}e^{ipr})\hat{a}_{p}=-\sum p^{2}\hat{a}_{p}$

Now $\hat{a}_{p}$ is annihilation operator annihilating a particle with momentum p.

So, Eq. $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$H=\sum \frac{p^{2}}{2m}\hat{a}^{+}_{p}\hat{a}_{p}\tag{3}$$

In the process of Eq. $(2)$, it seems that $\nabla$ does not act on $\hat{a}_{p}$.

So I get confused why $\nabla$ act on $\hat{a}(r)$ but not on $a_{p}$. Also if $b(x_{0},p_{0})$ annihilating a particle whose wavefunction is Gaussian shape with $(x_{0}，p_{0})$ centered, can $b$ be derivated over $x_{0}$?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a function $f(x)$  and express it as a Fourier transform
$$
f(x) = \int \frac{dk}{2\pi} \tilde f(k) e^{ikx},
$$
why would you expect the coefficients $\tilde f(k)$ to depend on $x$?  Is it not the same in you question? The $\hat a_p$ are, after all, just  Fourier coefficients of the $\hat a(r)$.